# dataContext binding to data

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am trying to understand the dataContext better and tried creating a dataContext referencing a document.

```
    <xp:this.dataContexts>
      <xp:dataContext var="doc1">
        <xp:this.value>
          <![CDATA[#{javascript:
          var db:NotesDatabase = sessionAsSigner.getDatabase("","privDb.nsf");
          var adoc:NotesDocument = db.createDocument();
          return adoc }]]>
        </xp:this.value>
     </xp:dataContext>
    </xp:this.dataContexts>
```

I then tried using EL and javascript to bind fields on my xpage to the dataContext

```
    <xp:inputText id="inputText2" value="#{doc1.lastname}"></xp:inputText>
    <xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="${javascript:doc1.firstname}"></xp:inputText>
```

But when I save, it does't save anything.

```
    <xp:button value="save" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
             refreshMode="complete">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                    print(doc1.getClass().getName() )
                    doc1.save();
                }]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
```

The print command showing me the class name is showing up as lotus.domino.local.Document

The document is saved to the database, but it has no values other than $UpdatedBy.  I can't seem to bind fields to the edit boxes.

The reason I am going down this path is twofold, 1. I want to use sessionAsSigner so I can keep the database security on the remote db (privDb.nsf) at No Access for anonymous and default, and 2. I want to learn a little more about dataContext, data sources and binding.  I have read the "easy" way of using a Public Document, using the $PublicAccess field, etc, which is the "Old School" Notes way, and yes, I could do it that way, but want to understand how to do it using dataContexts, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dataContext is basically a scoped variable, scoped lower than `viewScope` but higher than `requestScope`, scoped to a component. That component can be an XPage, a Custom Control or a Panel (yes, dataContexts can be added to a Panel too).

Like other scoped variables on the page, a simple save action does not save dataContexts. If you want a variable that's create-able and save-able, that's the Data Object. That has specific createObject and saveObject properties, where you define what should happen when they're called by the XPages runtime.

Similarly, like the other scoped variables, it needs to be serialized, so you cannot store a Domino object in them. So you can't store a NotesDocument in them. You need to wrap a normal Java object around a NotesDocument. With a greater understanding of XPages it becomes apparent that's what the dominoDocument datasource is doing (creating properties for all fields on the document, storing its note id, UNID, adding other properties like whether it's in edit mode or new etc).

A final point, as Jesse says, dataContexts are re-evaluated multiple times during a partial refresh. I haven't re-tested recently, but under 8.5.3 dataContexts bound to an XPage or Custom Control were re-evaluated more than dataContexts bound to a Panel, so I'd recommend the latter.

Comment: Thanks, Paul.  Jesse recommended a method that is similar to what I'm already doing and I will leave that code in place.  I want to take advantage of the XPage feature set so I will review the Data Object and createObject.  I have also read, here on stackoverflow, that many of these issues can be resolved by writing a bean so I am digesting as much introductory info as I can.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem that you're running into is that #{}-bound dataContexts are re-evaluated constantly, several times during a page load and, I believe, every time they're referenced. Generally, the rule of thumb with dataContexts (and don't get me wrong - I like them) is that they should either be extremely low-cost, like a quick mathematical calculation, or be ${}-bound. The latter wouldn't work here, though, since the document wouldn't survive past the first load.

The tack you may want to try is to use a dataContext like this:

```
<xp:dataContext var="docData" value="${javascript: new java.util.HashMap() }" />
```

Basically, using a simple object as a holding pen. Then, in the save action, create the new document and set all of the values from "docData" there, like:

```
var db = sessionAsSigner.getDatabase("", "privDb.nsf");
var doc = db.createDocument();
doc.replaceItemValue("firstname", docData.get("firstname"));
doc.replaceItemValue("lastname", docData.get("lastname"));
doc.save();
```

There are a few caveats to this approach:

- Each save will create a new document, rather than editing the existing one. You could change this by storing the UNID back into the map and fetching it from the DB, though
- It should work as-is in this case, but you'll have to be mindful of data types. For example, if you have a multi-value control, then the XPages runtime will probably create an `ArrayList`, which you would have to convert to a `Vector` for storage unless you're using the OpenNTF Domino API

And as a final note, that binding you have for firstname is almost definitely not what you want. That may just be an artifact of the testing you were doing, but I'd be remiss if I didn't mention it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Jesse.  I have a method in place, similar to what you recommend here, but differs in the primary datasource of document vs dataContext.  I use a simple data binding to a blank document in the current db, then when I save, I do what you suggest above, but with the newDoc.replaceItemValue("field","value").  The primary data binding is never saved.